# Can't set the native resolution for an external VGA 1080p monitor with xrandr or settings

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and I can't set the external 1920x1080p monitor connect by a VGA cable to its native resolution. By default on boot its set to 1024x768p and from settings I don't have a bigger option.
Hardware: Intel i7 4710HQ, Intel HD 4600, Nvidia 840M (tried with 460 property and X.Org Nouveau drivers)
What I tried: With xrandr I can set it to 1912x1080p and I works. For 1920x1080p, after I add the mode with xrandr, when I try to set it to that resolution in settings the monitor flashes black and gets back to the resolution set before it.
Have any idea how to fix it so I can use the monitor's resolution?
EDIT ->
Monitor model: Dell SE2419HR
Commands used:

```
cvt 1912 1080
xrandr --newmode "1912x1080_60.00"  171.25  1912 2032 2232 2552  1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA-1-1 "1912x1080_60.00"

cvt 1920 1080
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA-1-1 "1920x1080_60.00"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not given a make/model of the monitor or said how you attempted to use xrandr to set the resolution so I would suggest you edit your question with those details.

You need to use `cvt` to generate a "modeline" for example:
`cvt 1920 1080`
or with a refresh rate depending what your graphics/monitor can handle:
`cvt 1920 1080 60`

(Also, for some hardware you may have to use reduced timing mode: `cvt -r 1920 1080`)

Then you need to pass the generated modeline to xrandr for example:

`xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync`

Here is a good reference for [xrandr](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr#Adding_undetected_resolutions)

Comment: tried with reduced timing mode and it worked, thanks a lot