# Limited display resolution selection with NVidia gpu & drivers

Tags: nvidia, display, display-resolution

I've got an Ubuntu 20.04 workstation, featuring an NVidia RTX2080 gpu, and connected to a widescreen with a native resolution of 3440x1440.

For basic needs, the display works fine : by default, it's running at native 3440x1440.

But if I go into Settings->Display and try to select an alternate resolution, the choice is scarce, limited to 3440x1440, 1024x768 and 800x600. That's it. No other intermediate resolution is proposed.

It happens that I need to test such intermediate resolutions, like 1920x1080, but can't do it on this station.

However, when running a full-screen game which offers a choice of resolution on the same computer, a *ton* of choices are offered, and they all work great, indicating that there is no issue with neither the display, nor the gpu, nor the driver. Hence, it seems a limitation of Settings->Display.

I've tested multiple driver versions, they all feature the same (currently running 460.32.03).

Has anyone met the same kind of issue ? Is there a solution for it ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to manually add resolutions using `cvt` and `xrandr` if you are sure your graphics and monitor support the modes. See my recent post here and the link there:

[Can't set the native resolution for an external VGA 1080p monitor with xrandr or settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310551/cant-set-the-native-resolution-for-an-external-vga-1080p-monitor-with-xrandr-or/1310560#1310560)

Comment: I've actually already read your answer and tried it !
Unfortunately, it failed : `xrandr` returned a _bunch_ of errors, as if many entries coming from `cvt` were wrong, and it looked scary enough that I did not dare attempting more, due to a perceived risk of breaking desktop settings.

Comment: Actually tried it again, and got this result :
```
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  43
  Current serial number in output stream:  43
```

Comment: Nope, actually this was a new error due to previous `cvt` mode being still around. The actual error I got when trying to apply the new mode with `--addmode` : ```X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  43
  Current serial number in output stream:  44
```

Comment: I suggest you update your original question with exactly the command lines you are issuing.