# Ubuntu 20.04 resolution

Tags: 20.04, display-resolution

I am using ubuntu 20.04
The problem is the highest resolution it can go up to is 1024x768, which is terrible.

*-display
description: VGA compatible controller
product: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 2
bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
version: 02
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
resources: irq:30 memory:f7c00000-f7ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:ec90(size=8) memory:c0000-dfff

how can i set resolution to higher?

Comment: You should be able to add custom resolutions as long as your graphics hardware and your monitor support them. See here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310551/cant-set-the-native-resolution-for-an-external-vga-1080p-monitor-with-xrandr-or/1310560#1310560

Comment: i have seen the link and use the xrandr but when i restart my OS it goes back to 1024x768

Comment: You need to read the linked resource about permanently adding custom resolutions: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr#Permanently_adding_undetected_resolutions